# Is there a way to merge in the latest changes from develop to just one file?

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a branch off from develop called branch A which contains a file called F, in develop this file has been deleted.

In Github I have PR to merge branch A in to develop but Github says that Branch A has conflicts in file F

I cannot resolve these conflicts in Github as the file no longer exists in develop to compare it against

I don't need this file and I'm happy to delete it on branch A however if I don't believe I can just delete this file as then my PR will be trying to delete a file that doesn't exist in develop when I do bring in the latest changes to develop .. maybe I'm wrong?

I do not want to merge in the latest changes that have been done on develop to branch A just yet

Is there a way to merge in the latest changes from develop to just one file? Or another solution to my issue

Hope that all makes sense

Comment: Well, unless I am mistaken and the workflow is different when working with GitHub and PRs, you should deal with integration issues in the feature branch. Therefore, once your feature is completed you should be either merging `develop` into `A`, or rebasing `A` onto `develop` and fix conflicts then. Rebasing is cleaner IMO, but you would have to force push into `A` on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict arises because one side modifies a file which does not exist on the other side.

Checkout branch A then delete your unwanted file and push that on remote A. Then make your PR between A and develop, your conflict should be gone.